# Can we pass a list of id in UserId on a soql query made on UserRecordAccess

Tags: apex, soql, bulkification, userrecordaccess

I am trying to find access levels on a certain record and this falls in a body of a trigger for which i need to bulkify the data coming in. So is there a possibility of passing a list of ids in the following query:

```
SELECT RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId=:listofUserIds AND HasReadAccess = true AND RecordId IN :allRecordIds LIMIT 200
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Executing this code in the anonymous window will throw an error.

```
List<Id> listofUserIds = new List<Id>{''};
List<Id> allRecordIds = new List<Id>{''};

List<UserRecordAccess> res = [SELECT RecordId 
FROM UserRecordAccess 
WHERE UserId IN :listofUserIds AND HasReadAccess = true AND RecordId IN :allRecordIds LIMIT 200];
```

[image]

Comment: Eduard - your `Note` about the equals operator is not true. I used to think this too but the equals operator bound to a collection works fine. I may have learned this from sfdcfox on this site.

Comment: @cropredy, thanks for your comment. I edited my answer.